# Time function from python script from the command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeit

I'd like to time functions from scripts, preferably not modifying said scripts (i.e adding timer decorators, or functions).

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect you to research things on your own before posting here.

Comment: My bad @Prune, I meant to answer my own question from the start, so did not know how to actually proof my work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line, run *timeit* module as a script passing the additional *setup* argument (-s). The setup should import the function you wish to time from your script.

Finally, remember to add the call to that function.

WARNING: setup will run once, importing your script. Import runs all "unprotected code", so remember to use the `if __name__ == "__main__"` convention to split function/object declarations from actual execution.

Imagine the following script.py

```
import time

print('This will be run on import')

def fun():
    pass

def very_complex_function_that_takes_an_hour_to_run():
    time.sleep(3600)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Nothing beyond the if condition will be run on import")
    very_complex_function_that_takes_an_hour_to_run()
```

Let's time `fun`, running it 100 times.

```
$ python -m timeit -s 'from test import fun' -n 100 'fun()'
```

Output

```
This will be run on import
100 loops, best of 5: 66.6 nsec per loop
```